# C: Many if to less lines

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, flags, ls

For an exercise, I must recode the "ls" function. Currently I'm using if(strcmp to gestionate the flags but I'm wondering if there is another way to do it with less lines. Thanks in advance and there you have my code.

```
void my_ls(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-a") == 0)
        minus_a(argc, argv);
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-d") == 0)
        minus_d(argc, argv);
    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-F") == 0)
        minus_cap_f(argc, argv);
    multi_ls(argc, argv);
}
```

Comment: You can remove all the new line characters. ;)

Comment: What do you mean by this? P.S: This is just the beginning of my function. I have to make all the flags. I've heard about some pointer on function for this but I don't understand how it works.

Comment: He means that C does not care about line structure in most cases. You could simply put your whole function in one line.

Comment: You can use `getopt()`.

Comment: Well, I'm not allowed to use getopt() and I can't put my whole function on the same line since I can't pass 80 chars on a line. Also, If I use more than 3 if, it's not ok.

Comment: Concatenate all the arguments then `system(argv)` (not a serious suggestion sorry)

Comment: @Asez Can you please update the question that you don't want to use `getopt()`?

Comment: I'm not allowed to use getopt() by my teachers.

Comment: instead of comparing again and again all the strings, just use `else` to avoid redundant comparisons

Comment: You entire approach may be wrong if the goal is to replicate the command-line options of `ls`.  How do you plan on handling something like `ls -lat ...`, where multiple options are combined into one `argv` string passed to your code?

Comment: @AndrewHenie Yep, that's the main problem. I'm struggling in putting multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (argv[1][0] == '-' && argv[1][1] != 0 && argv[1][2] == 0)
{
    switch (argv[1][1])
    {
        case 'a':
            ...
            break;
        case 'd':
            ...
            break;
        case 'F':
            ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, you probably wanna make sure that `argc > 1` to begin with.

Comment: Thanks! Have you an idea about how to manage multiple flags. not only argv[1]. Like ./my_ls -a -d -F ...etc

Comment: @Asez: Implement a function which will take the string as input, parse it according to those `-` characters and return an array of flags as output. Use an enumeration for these flags, so that you don't have to parse them as individual strings again outside the function.